# Can't get the PHPExcel and CodeIgniter integration to work

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

This has been confusing me for days, I can't get the code below to work:

```
public function index (){
    //load our new PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    //activate worksheet number 1
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //name the worksheet
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('test worksheet');
    //set cell A1 content with some text
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'This is just some text value');
    //change the font size
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(20);
    //make the font become bold
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    //merge cell A1 until D1
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:D1');
    //set aligment to center for that merged cell (A1 to D1)
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

    $filename='just_some_random_name.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    }


}
```

**All I get is a blank page**. I tried tracing the codes to determine why it won't work and the line *`$this->load->library('excel');`*
is causing it.

I have created the excel.php file in /libraries, pasted the code from the example on the web.

Can someone help me on this one please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you install PHPExcel with CodeIgniter.

See you answer here:
[PHPExcel error in CodeIgniter "Unable to load the requested class: iofactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028175/phpexcel-error-in-codeigniter-unable-to-load-the-requested-class-iofactory)

Drop the phpexcel folder into application/third-party and create a library.
(for library use the class proviced by @devrooms in his answer)

Then do the following in controllers:

```
$this->load->library("excel");
$this->excel->load("/path/to/input.xls");
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', "whatever");
$this->excel->save("/path/to/output.xls");
```

If the above is not working see this answer to **deactivate the php safe mode** on your server

[phpexel and codeigniter getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281813/phpexel-and-codeigniter-getting-error)